# Deep Learning for Acoustic Emission concrete fracture speciments: regression on-set time and classification of type of failure

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, conv-neural-network, anomaly-detection, faster-rcnn

How can I use deep learning for both regression and classification tasks?

I am facing a problem with acoustic emission on fracture with concrete speciment. The objective is to find automatically the on-set time instant (time at the beginning of the acoustic emission) and the slope with the peak value to determine the kind of fracture (mode I or mode II based on the raise angle RA).
[image: Definition of onset time and raise angle to classify fracture]

I have tried Regional CNN to work with images of the signals [Fine-tuning Faster-RCNN using pytorch](https://www.kaggle.com/yerramvarun/fine-tuning-faster-rcnn-using-pytorch/notebook), but unfortunately the results are not outstanding up to now.

[image: Object detection with Faster-RCNN pytorch]

I would like to work with sequences (time series) of amplitude data according to a certain sampling frequency, but they have different length each. How can I deal with this problem?

Can I make a 1D-CNN which makes a sort of anomaly detection based on the supervised point that I can mark manually on training examples?

I have a certain number of recordings which I would like to exploit to train the model sampled at 100Hz. In examples on anomaly detection like [Timeseries anomaly detection using an Autoencoder](https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_anomaly_detection/), they use the same time series and they perform a window with sliding 1 time step in order to obtain about 3700 to train their neural network. Instead I have different number of recordings (time series) each of them with a certain on-set time instant  and different global length in seconds. How can I manage it?

I actually need the time instant of the beginning of the signal and the maximum point to define the raise angle and classify the type of fracture. Can I make classification directly with CNN simultaneously with regression tasks of the on-set time instant?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Detecting the time-points is an (Sound) Event Detection problem - it is usually not treated as a regression problem, but classification - potentially using a sequence as output. See https://openresearch.surrey.ac.uk/esploro/outputs/journalArticle/Sound-Event-Detection-A-Tutorial/99590523702346

Comment: You need to chop your input into fixed-length sequences (potentially with overlap).

Comment: If you label the data with the classes {Mode I, Mode II, NotCrack } then a neural net can learn that directly. The features A/RT are not needed for such a classifier.

Comment: Thank you very much @JonNordby for your interesting suggestion ! I will have a more deep look to the Sound Event Detection which seems to be the exact thing that I need! I have to chop input in fixed length (defining a certain time window) but it not clear to me how to deal this with different sequence that I want to use as training data. Moreover these time window have to overlap? But the strong labelling have to be done for each of them right? Thank you in advance

Comment: You should label the original data with time-positions of each event (and its class). Then you use these labels to compute the correct label for each fixed-length window. The windows should preferably cover an entire event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved, thanks to the fundamental suggestion by @JonNordby, using Sound Event Detection method. We adopted and readapted the code from [GitHub YashNita](https://github.com/YashNita/sound-event-detection-winning-method).

I labelled the data according to the following image:
[image]

Then, I adopted the method for extracting features from computing the spectrogram of the input signals:
[image]

And finally we were able to get a more precise output recognition of the Seismic Event Detection which is directly connected to the Acoustic Emission Event detection, obtaining the following result:
[image]

For the moment, only the event recognition phase was done, but it would be simple to readapt also to conduct classification of mode I or mode II of cracking.